# C: Acces bytes in mallocated memory

Tags: c, malloc

I have allocated array of void
I need to acces bytes of allocated memory

```
void* array = (void*) malloc(12);
array[0] = 0;
```

It returns me this error:

```
main.c:9: error: invalid use of void expression
     array[0] = 0;
     ^
```

Is there any way how to do it ?
Thanks!

Comment: You do not have to cast to `void*` explicitly in C. Casts from `T*` to `void*` are implicit.

Comment: By jhow many bytes should `array + 1` increment `array`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `array` is a `void`-pointer. And `void` (in C) means 'has no type'. So when you dereference it (like `array[0]`) the compiler has no idea what that means.

To access bytes you need a `char` type, which is actually the C-equivalent of a byte (a remnant from the days when characters would still fit into (8-bit) bytes).

So declare your array as:

```
char * array = malloc(12);
```

Also note that you don't have to cast the result of `malloc` (especially in your case since it already returns a `void *`). And, if you want just the 12 bytes and only use them locally (within the function or translation-unit that declares it) then you can just use a 'proper array':

```
char array[12];
```

This has the added bonus that you don't need to `free` it afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `char` or `unsigned char` rather than `void` to access the bytes:

```
char *array = malloc(12);
array[0] = 0;
```

`malloc()` returns a `void` pointer because it doesn't know the type you're allocating.  You can't access the memory via that `void` pointer; you need to tell the compiler how to treat the block of memory.  To treat it as bytes, use `char` or `unsigned char`.

Comment: so when I have created void pointer then I have to create second char pointer ?

Comment: @Peter: A pointer must point to an actual type before you can follow it in order to read or write the memory that it points to.